# Add tags within a PowerPoint

Tags: term-store, powerpoint

I have created terms for a Powerpoint presentation via the term store and added it via Sharepoint. E.g., for a „Country“ column it is „Germany“. How can I insert this tag within the presentation so that the title page says: „Country: Germany“ and once i switch the property to France it updates the slide as well?